# DiskSpaceHealthIndicator reports 0 bytes available running in Docker under user

Tags: docker, spring-boot, jhipster, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot application generated by JHipster.
The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ENV SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED=ALWAYS \
    JHIPSTER_SLEEP=0 \
    JAVA_OPTS=""

# Add a jhipster user to run our application so that it doesn't need to run as root
RUN adduser -D -s /bin/sh jhipster
WORKDIR /home/jhipster

ADD entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 entrypoint.sh && chown jhipster:jhipster entrypoint.sh
USER jhipster

ADD *.war app.war

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

After starting the application I see lines like these and the `/management/health` endpoint never returns a positive response:

`o.s.b.a.system.DiskSpaceHealthIndicator  : Free disk space below threshold. Available: 0 bytes (threshold: 10485760 bytes)`

**Why is this health check failing even though there is enough space?**

```
$ df -h

Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs                     2.7G         0      2.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1                15.3G      2.6G     11.8G  18% /dev/termination-log
/dev/vda1                15.3G      2.6G     11.8G  18% /etc/hosts
shm                      64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     2.7G     12.0K      2.7G   0% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/kcore
tmpfs                    64.0M         0     64.0M   0% /proc/timer_list
tmpfs                     2.7G         0      2.7G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs                     2.7G         0      2.7G   0% /sys/firmware
```

---

*Edit:*

```
$ df -k /
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                      0         0         0   0% /
```

Comment: What if you run `df -k /` inside the container? Can you write to the directory from inside the container? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11058

Comment: @Mike I've added the output of `df -k /`. I've also deployed this container to a different cluster (rather than Minikube) and it's running fine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with minikube and why it might be making a volume with no space, but you can always disable the Disk Space health check (`management.health.diskspace.enabled=false`) or configure it to use a more meaningful path inside the container (`management.health.diskspace.path=/new/path/`)

Comment: Thanks @Mike, that's a good suggestion. I tried to test it, but it seems restarting minikube (local Kubernetes cluster) solved the original problem. The good old "have you tried turning it off and on again?" :-(

Comment: Ah yes, my favorite remedy for production issues :)